# Table generated from DB using sevlet not getting submitted when form is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jsp, servlets

I am creating a table based on the input from DB and displaying it inside my div as below:

Servlet:

```
out.print("<table id=prev class=display nowrap stripe row-border order-column>");
   out.print("<thead>");
   out.print("<tr>" +
"<th>Form Id</th>\n" +
"                <th>Form Name</th>\n" +
"                <th>Open</th>\n" +
"                <th>Report</th>\n" +
"                <th>View</th>\n" +
"                <th>Insert</th>\n" +
"                <th>Update</th>\n" +
"                <th>Delete</th>\n" +
"                <th>Approve Transaction</th>\n" +
"                <th>Reject Transaction</th>\n" +
"                   </tr>");
   out.print("</thead>");
    out.print("<tfoot>");
   out.print("<tr>" +
"<th>Form Id</th>\n" +
"                <th>Form Name</th>\n" +
"                <th>Open</th>\n" +
"                <th>Report</th>\n" +
"                <th>View</th>\n" +
"                <th>Insert</th>\n" +
"                <th>Update</th>\n" +
"                <th>Delete</th>\n" +
"                <th>Approve Transaction</th>\n" +
"                <th>Reject Transaction</th>\n" +
"                   </tr>");
   out.print("</tfoot>");
   out.println("<tbody>");
 while(rs1.next())
    {out.print("<tr><td name=prvlg>"+rs1.getInt("FORM_ID")+"</td>"
           + "<td name=prvlg>"+rs1.getString("FORM_NAME")+"</td>");
   if(form1==1){ out.print("<td name=prvlg><input type=checkbox checked=checked></td>");}
   else { out.print("<td name=prvlg><input type=checkbox></td>");}
   if(report==1)
       { out.print("<td name=prvlg><input type=checkbox checked=checked></td>");}
   else { out.print("<td name=prvlg><input type=checkbox></td>");}
   if(view==1)
       { out.print("<td name=prvlg><input type=checkbox checked=checked></td>");}
   else { out.print("<td name=prvlg><input type=checkbox></td>");}
    if(insert1==1)
       { out.print("<td name=prvlg><input type=checkbox checked=checked></td>");}
   else { out.print("<td name=prvlg><input type=checkbox></td>");}
     if(update==1)
       { out.print("<td name=prvlg><input type=checkbox checked=checked></td>");}
   else { out.print("<td name=prvlg><input type=checkbox></td>");}
      if(delete==1)
       { out.print("<td name=prvlg><input type=checkbox checked=checked></td>");}
   else { out.print("<td name=prvlg><input type=checkbox></td>");}
       if(isapproved==1)
       { out.print("<td name=prvlg><input type=checkbox checked=checked></td>");}
   else { out.print("<td name=prvlg><input type=checkbox></td>");}
       if(not_approved==1)
       { out.print("<td name=prvlg><input type=checkbox checked=checked></td>");}
   else { out.print("<td name=prvlg><input type=checkbox></td>");}

   }
   out.print("</tbody></table>");
}
```

and displaying it as here:

```
 if ((zreq.readyState == 4) && (zreq.status == 200)) {

                            document.getElementById("user_prev").innerHTML = zreq.responseText;
                           $("#parent").DataTable({
                               dom: 't',
                           });
```

and div is inside the form. when submitting it, all the other information getting submitted but except the contents of table.

```
String td[]=request.getParameterValues("prvlg");
```

it is always null. Can anyone suggest me where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form field (input, textarea, select,..) should have an `name` attribute i order to be submitted.

Lines like:

```
<input type=checkbox checked=checked>
```

should look like:

```
<input name=parameterName type=checkbox checked=checked>
```

Then on the server you can access this parameter with:

```
request.getParameter("parameterName");
```

You have set the `name` attribute on a `td`-tag:

```
<td name=prvlg>
```

But only form elements get submitted.

EDIT:
In order to submit other values, they should be also in `input`.
You want to submit also the first two rows:

```
{out.print("<tr><td name=prvlg>"+rs1.getInt("FORM_ID")+"</td>"
       + "<td name=prvlg>"+rs1.getString("FORM_NAME")+"</td>");
```

Then add a hidden input in the table cells:

```
{out.print("<tr><td name=prvlg><input name='formId' type='hidden' value='" + rs1.getInt("FORM_ID") + "'></td>"
       + "<td name=prvlg><input name='formName' type='hidden' value='" + rs1.getString("FORM_NAME") + "'></td>");
```

The `<input type=hidden>` is not visible in the browser, but it is submitted.

Comment: In this only checked values submitted. But how could I also submit, unchecked checkbox value? because i need to pass these values to a function in the sequence.

Comment: That's right. Only checked checkboxes are submitted. For handling unchecked values, you can add additional hidden inputs with value true or false for each checkbox and transfer the changes from the chackbox to the hidden input with javascript.

Comment: Thank you So much. but how to do that? i can't give any id to the hidden field as the fields are generated dynamically.  then how could i set the value of them?

Comment: you can go the other way around. The data come for the Database right? So you can iterate all columns, you used normarly to generate the jsp table, after the form is submitted. And check in the loop which checkboxes were submitten, all others are false. Or something like that.

Comment: is there any way o make out which checkbox belong to which cell checked in a table?